# ArcGIS Server simple link with SQL Server database

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, sql-server, database

I am using ArcGIS Server 10 to create Rich Internet Application with embeded Maps.
Basicaly, I created an Optimized Map Service on ArcGIS Server, from an MXD file (produced with Arc Map). I have different layers of data from shapefile, but what I want is to add XY data from a database (SQL Server).

I create a Database Connection through "Add OLE DB Connection" in ArcCatalog, and added my data with "Add XY Data" in ArcMap.
(My Table that I am querying is very simple: Id, latitude, longitude)
After that I can see my data (dots) on the map within ArcMap.
But when I publish the Map Service from the MXD, I have an error saying that the layer's data source is not supported.

Is there any way to create a layer from a (Non spatial) table (from database) that just contains basic coordinates (XY data)? I want to directly link the Map Services with the database, to ensure that the map is automatically updated when the table changes.

Answer (score 2):

try exporting the event layer formed by add XY process to shape file it will work

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Server 10 does not support layers added with the "Add XY Data" in an optimized MSD map document.  It does support them if you publish your map using the MXD document, though.

If performance is a concern, you can publish just the XY data (also called an Event Layer) in a standalone service as an MXD document, and the rest of your layers in the optimized MSD document.

I don't know how ArcGIS Server 10.1 treats event layers.